# Does a child class inherit the Quartz.net [PersistJobDataAfterExecution] attribute from a parent class

Tags: c#, inheritance, attributes, quartz.net

In Quartz.net, if I declare a class with the `[PersistJobDataAfterExecution]` or the `[DisallowConcurrentExecution]` attributes that implements the IJob interface, will classes that inherit this class also inherit these attribute?

```
[PersistJobDataAfterExecution]
[DisallowConcurrentExecution]
public abstract class ParentJob : IJob
{
    //...
}

public class ChildJob : ParentJob
{
    //...
}
```

So in the code snippet above, does `ChildJob` have the `[PersistJobDataAfterExecution]` or `[DisallowConcurrentExecution]` attributes?

If they are not, how can I make them be inherited without altering the Quartz.net source code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**They are inherited**, not because they are defined to be inheritable, but by how Quartz.net checks for the presence of attributes on classes:

```
public static bool IsAttributePresent(Type typeToExamine, Type attributeType)
{
    return typeToExamine.GetCustomAttributes(attributeType, true).Length > 0;
}
```

<sup>[Source](https://github.com/quartznet/quartznet/blob/e4e71b78bea5a4b7cb41408902207e9880b027ad/src/Quartz/Util/ObjectUtils.cs)</sup>

In [`GetCustomAttributes(Type, bool)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwc6ew1d(v=vs.110).aspx), the `bool` parameter can be:

> **true** to search this member's inheritance chain to find the attributes; otherwise, false. This parameter is ignored for properties and events; see Remarks.

Comment: Sorry maybe I was ambiguous, I meant if I create a parent class with the attributes, will child classes inherit the attribute?

Comment: I have edited the question, it was more just the wrong question than ambiguous. Sorry about that!

Comment: Sorry, I read this all a bit wrong. I have what should be a correct answer now.

Comment: Thanks! Can I change that without editing the source code for Quartz.net? i.e. I desire for them to be inherited - how can I go about it? (I'll add this to the question as well)

Comment: See my last edit...I'm slightly confused -- the attribute itself is not set to be inheritable, but the utility method is honoring the "inheritance chain."

Comment: Got it! They actually are inherited. See my (hopefully final) edit.

Comment: perhaps you can clarify, it seems to me that the `[DisallowConcurrentExecution]` attribute will stop any derived class job instances running concurrently to other instance of different types (sharing the same parent) rather than just inheriting the attribute that make them not run concurrently with the same type (not the same parent type) is that makes sense?

Comment: @Dan: I am actually not familiar with Quartz.net at all. It's true I dug through its source code to find this answer, but for other questions about its functionality I'm going to be useless :). You should, however, ask that as a separate question and maybe somebody else may know the answer.